# Как правильно сравнивать элементы массивов с определенными значениями?

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы, visual-c++, сравнение

VC17 нигде не пишет, что есть ошибка, но в файл вообще ничего не сохраняет. Помогите разрешить данную проблему.
Вот кусок кода, где есть потенциальный недочет\ошибка

```
                                                        ofstream fol("zadanie.txt");
                                                        fol.open("zadanie.txt");
                                                        char a[] = "A";
                                                        for (i = 0; i < chislo_ludi; i++)
                                                        {
                                                            while (ludi[i].fio[0] == a[0])
                                                            {
                                                                while (ludi[i].math == 8. || ludi[i].math == 9.)
                                                                {
                                                                    fol << ludi[i].fio << "   " << ludi[i].god << "   " << ludi[i].grupa << "   " << ludi[i].math << "   " << ludi[i].fizika << "   " << ludi[i].inform << "   " << ludi[i].himia << "   " << ludi[i].sr_bal << endl;

                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
```

Comment: @DrawnRacсoon  Попробовал, но не работает все равно

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
ofstream fol("zadanie.txt");
                                                                char a[] = "A";
                                                                for (i = 0; i < chislo_ludi; i++)
                                                                {
                                                                    if ((ludi[i].fio[0] == a[0]) && ((ludi[i].math == 8.) || (ludi[i].math == 9.)))
                                                                    {

                                                                            fol << ludi[i].fio << "   " << ludi[i].god << "   " << ludi[i].grupa << "   " << ludi[i].math << "   " << ludi[i].fizika << "   " << ludi[i].inform << "   " << ludi[i].himia << "   " << ludi[i].sr_bal << endl;


                                                                    }
                                                                }

                                                                fol.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

После `ofstream fol("zadanie.txt");` файл уже открыт. При попытке открыть его снова

> `fol.open("zadanie.txt");`

произойдёт ошибка и поток перейдёт в состояние `fail`. Удалите строку `fol.open("zadanie.txt");` или объявите поток без параметров `ofstream fol;`